# How can i make the Screen Name element required?

Tags: member-management

I need to make the screen_name input field on my CP Register Member form required.

Here is what I currently have:

```
// Screen Name
$this->table->add_row(array(
    form_label(required().lang('Client Name'), 'screen_name').NBS.form_error('screen_name'),
    form_input(array(
        'id'    => 'screen_name',
        'name'  => 'screen_name',
        'class' => 'field',
        'maxlength' => 50,
        'value' => set_value('screen_name')
        )
    )
)
);
```

I am not sure what else I need to do to make this a required field. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information about what specifically in your code isn't working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a custom add-on you are building, you need to use the ExpressionEngine [form validation class](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/form_validation.html) to truly make it required.

There is even a method specifically for screen name.

```
ee()->form_validation->set_rules('screen_name', 'Screen Name', 'required|valid_screen_name');
```

See [valid_screen_name](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/form_validation.html#valid-screen-name)

There are other rules you can use, too. Check the form validation class [Rule Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) in the CodeIgniter docs.

**UPDATE**

Since you're referring to the Control Panel's Members > Register Member form...

Unless you find or build an extension to do this for you, you actually have to make a tiny modification to the core to make this happen.

The following is based on EE 2.7.2, but should be similar for older versions.

Make the modification in /system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php. Around line 2170 inside the new_member_form() method you just need to add a "required" rule to the validation on the "screen_name" field.

So the rules for screen_name should look like this:

```
'rules' => 'required|trim|valid_screen_name[new]'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback.  I actually am just trying to set this up within the views > members > register.php file.  I also have been trying to figure out the Libraries > Validate.php screen_name validation but I am not sure confident with either. Where would I apply that class?

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated my answer. What version of EE are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.7.2 so that worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: tip: and write it down inside a changes.txt so you know what files you need to edit after upgrading to the next EE version.